# What's the best way to strip XML tags so I can process the contained plist in Android

Tags: android, xml, plist

I need to parse a pList in Android, from an http response. The response is for example -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message xmlns:ns2="http://books.campionreader.com/data_exchange" status="0">
    <GenericDictionary>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>objects</key>
                <array>
                .....
                .....
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </GenericDictionary>
</Message>
```

From the above response, I ONLY need the pList stuff, none of the surrounding tags, as this results in the actual pList parsing to fail.

Testing by copying the entire plist attributes into a .plist file in /res/raw is no problem, as I can manually remove all the *xml*, *Message*, *GenericDictionary* tags, but I need to do this programmatically.

I'm using [dd.plist](https://code.google.com/p/plist/) to do the actual pList parsing, and it works perfectly with a raw .plist, until I try with the actual server response and obviously throws errors due to the extra unwanted XML.

I thought I could remove the unwanted tags with a buffered reader and ignore specific lines, but the server response is a single (and very long) line without formatting.

I actually have the desired plist by using the following code, but I'm sure there is something I'm missing and hoping someone here can set me straight!

```js
public String GetPListFromXMLResponse(ByteArrayInputStream inputStream) {
        String plist = "";

        if (inputStream != null) {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();

            try {
                parser.setInput(inputStream, null);

                int eventType = parser.getEventType();

                String name = null;
                String key = null;

                HashMap<String, Object> dict = null;
                ArrayList<Object> array = null;

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    switch (eventType) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                            //Log.d(TAG, "START_DOCUMENT");
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            name = parser.getName();
                            //Log.d("XMLParsing name -", name);

                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("dict")) {
                                // root dict element, store it in string
                                plist = plist + "<" + name.toString() + ">";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("plist")) {
                                // plist found, start storing text until plist end tag
                                plist = plist + "<" + name.toString() + ">";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("key")) {
                                key = parser.nextText();
                                if (key != null) {
                                    plist = plist + "<key>" + key.toString() + "</key>";
                                }
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("integer")) {
                                plist = plist + "<integer>" + parser.nextText() + "</integer>";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
                                plist = plist + "<string>" + parser.nextText() + "</string>";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("array")) {
                                plist = plist + "<" + name.toString() + ">";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                                plist = plist + "<" + name.toString() + "/>";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                                plist = plist + "<" + name.toString() + "/>";
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            name = parser.getName();

                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("dict")) {
                                //end dict tag found, write it out
                                plist = plist + "</" + name.toString() + ">";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("array")) {
                                // end plist tag found, write it out
                                plist = plist + "</" + name.toString() + ">";
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("plist")) {
                                // end plist tag found, write it out
                                plist = plist + "</" + name.toString() + ">";
                            }

                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
                            //Log.d(TAG, "END_DOCUMENT");
                            break;

                    }
                    eventType = parser.next();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        //some text items may contain an ampersand. Need to convert this otherwise there is a SAXError
        plist = plist.replace("&", "&amp;");
        plist = plist.replace("amp;amp;", "amp;");

        return plist;
```

I'm sure this isn't the correct or best method, and while it works, I'd much prefer to do it properly, as this could cause obvious issues in the future!

Note - The server response CANNOT be changed as the iOS version of the app would be effected, so I'm left to work with what I'm given.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't paying close enough attention. If existing plist libraries don't handle your input properly, parsing the XML is going to be your best option. I haven't used plist parsing libraries, so I do not know their abilities and limitations.

Comment: Thanks, it just seemed like a long winded way of doing it. I thought I might be able to ignore whitespace (or similar) when getting the server response, or just simply say "get the plist element from this resource", but I guess it's not that simple. What I have done works, it's just ugly :) The plist parser I'm using only accepts plist format with no extra stuff I guess, and it is up to me to strip the extra stuff before hand!